# what does IP masking mean in this paper?

Tags: ip

SO on page 6 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.02656.pdf) it says:

> Furthermore, since there is the possibility that the
> NN attempts to learn classifying the packets using their
> IP addresses, as the dataset is captured using a limited
> number of hosts and servers, we decided to prevent
> this over-fitting by masking the IP addresses in the IP
> header.

What are the processes to mask the IP exactly? Does it put zeros? or remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are the processes to mask the IP exactly? Does it put zeros? or remove it?

The idea of "masking" is to hide that piece of data from the program that's analyzing the dataset.  The exact method isn't stated.  You'd have to ask the authors.

Comment: Thanks. So would you please name some usual methods for masking the IP?

Comment: It all depends on how the data is being analyzed.  There is no "usual" method.  It's best to ask the authors how they did it.